# ORA-06550 PLS-00103: expecting one of the following ( type <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> and ORA-06550:PLS-00103:

Tags: oracle

```
 DECLARE
e_id employee.e_id%type;SALARY employee.salary%type;CURSOR empsa1
IS
  SELECT e_id,
         salary
  FROM   employee;BEGIN
  open empsa1;LOOP
    FETCH empsa1
    INTO  e_id,
          salary;EXIT
  WHEN empsa1 % NOT found;INSERT INTO empsa1 VALUES
                (
                            e_id,
                            salary
                )
end/LOOP;close empsa1;END;
```

Comment: Code only questions are a bit rude; if you had an error like this, would you print out your code, walk over to a coworker, put the page on their desk and just say the error message to them? Probably not - there would be a bit of chat about what you're trying to do, ask them if they would take a look etc. Consider us in a similar fashion

Comment: I've formatted your code, but I've left it as-pasted (which is a bit of a mess with indentation that is all over the place) - if it doesn't look right, it would be good if you could fix it up. If that IS how it looks.. well, for your own and your future coworkers' sanity it would be good if you could fix it up..

Answer (score 0):

There were syntax errors in your code. Apart from that, you were inserting data into a cursor. As per my understanding, we can't insert data into cursor. Check the below code, and change table name in insert accordingly.

Hope this would help.

```
declare
    e_id     employee.e_id%type;
    salary   employee.salary%type;
    cursor empsa1 is select
                         e_id,
                         salary
                       from
                         employee;

begin
    open empsa1;
    loop
        fetch empsa1 into
            e_id,
            salary;
        exit when empsa1%notfound;
        insert into <table_name_where_you_want_to_insert_data> values (
            e_id,
            salary
        );
        commit;

    end loop;

    close empsa1;
end;
```